# How to access value of Ember Select view from controller?

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I'm building a simple form that has a few textboxes and a select dropdown, which uses a list of other objects as it's data.

So far, I have everything hooked up so when a user hits submit, the text form values are grabbed and a new object is created.

The problem I'm having is I can't access my select view's value.

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="courses"
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       selectionBinding="SD.StudentAddController.newCourse"}}
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but cannot figure out how to grab the value of the select field in my controller.

I access all the other text fields with (since they're bound to my controller's properties):

```
this.get('<fieldname>');
```

I can't get the select view to bind to my controller's property 'newCourse'... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was incorrectly referencing the controller to bind my newCourse value to.

I changed "SD.StudentAddController.newCourse" to "controller.newCourse" and it's working.

So the final select view hbs code was:

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="courses"
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       selectionBinding="controller.newCourse"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember Select's selectBinding binds the selected Object ...

http://jsbin.com/uxojek/3/edit